Trying to move a pipeline in azure devops to /archived using powershell
I have a working script that toggles the isdisabled flag for a repo. I need the script to also move the associated pipeline to /archived. I can do this manually in the ADO UI by going to pipelines then clicking the 3 dots next to the pipeline and selecting rename/move. Then a small window pops up with the option to rename or move. in the move box I type /archived and I am able to move the pipeline to /archived. However, I need this to be done programmatically with powershell.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To move an Azure DevOps pipeline to a different folder programmatically using PowerShell, you'll need to use the Azure DevOps REST API.
Try this script and make sure to replace "your_personal_access_token", "your_organization", "your_project", and "your_pipeline_id" with your actual Azure DevOps details. This script will authenticate to Azure DevOps, fetch the pipeline details, update the path to /archived, and apply the changes.
# Install the Azure DevOps PowerShell Module if not already installed
# Install-Module -Name Az.DevOps -Scope CurrentUser

# Set your personal access token (PAT)
$pat = 'your_personal_access_token'
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))

# Define the organization, project, and pipeline ID
$organization = "your_organization"
$project = "your_project"
$pipelineId = "your_pipeline_id"

# Get the pipeline details
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/$pipelineId?api-version=6.0-preview.1" `
                              -Method Get `
                              -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

# Define the new path for the pipeline
$pipelinePath = "/archived"
$pipeline.configuration.path = $pipelinePath

# Prepare the request body for updating the pipeline path
$body = @{
    folder = $pipelinePath
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Update the pipeline path
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/$pipelineId?api-version=6.0-preview.1" `
                  -Method Patch `
                  -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo); "Content-Type"="application/json"} `
                  -Body $body

